# How to prevent DataGridView from jumping to beginning after cell editing?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

After user finished editing a cell in the table, the first row get focused and view "jumps" to the beginning of the table. How to prevent this? I've tried to store current cell's index, like that:

```
private void ANNUAL_COMMON_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    rowNum = ((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.RowIndex;
}
```

And then restoring it:

```
private void ANNUAL_COMMON_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    ((DataGridView)sender).FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = rowNum;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I've experimented with different events, like MouseClick, CellLeave etc., and got nothing. Is there some other way? I can provide additional details if required.

P.S. Strange, but the value of ((DataGridView)sender).FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex not changing, it's zero before and after the assignment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does rowNum retain it's value across these 2 events?

Comment: Yes, rowNum stores value properly.

Comment: It looks like all rows should be of the same height if you want `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` setter to work, according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820276/datagridview-firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex-not-working-at-the-bottom-of-the-gr).

Comment: I've made all the row heights equal, still no effect.